# Дощовитий чи дощовий день?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, правопис, українські-словники

Помітила, що є два варіанти вживання.

Comment: Вітаємо на Ukrainian Language.SE. Будь ласка, додайте до свого запитання, що ви шукали і яких висновків ви вже дійшли. Почитайте про наші [критерії](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%96-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%96-good-questions-and-good-answers), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. Ви завжди можете виправити своє питання або відповідь за допомогою посилання edit.

Comment: Дякую. Дійшла до висновку, що правильно дощовитий день.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/doshhovutuj-i-doshhovuj) чудовий сайт для новачків, все доступно пояснено

[image: дощ]

**Дощовитий** – це "багатий на дощі": дощовитий день, дощовита осінь, дощовита погода, дощовитий рік.

**Дощовий** – відносний прикметник до слова "дощ": дощова вода, дощові краплини, дощові хмари, дощовий черв’як.

Визначення є в СУМ-11 
[Дощовий](http://sum.in.ua/s/doshhovyj) та [Дощовитий](http://sum.in.ua/s/Doshhovytyj), хоч і пишуть *що те саме*, та на мою думку, краще розмежовувати ці два слова.

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9/)

> Замініть прикметник **дощовий**, якщо мовиться про щось, багате дощами, на
>   стилістично кращий варіант: **дощовитий**.

Comment: але сум каже, що дощовитий - те саме, що дощовий.